# Can I make a quickly SQL call in the MainThread? Delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi

I have several SQL calls in my Delphi VCL application which uses FireDac to call a MySQL Server to get some data.

However, I am doing all this calls inside the `UIThread` because they take only a couple of milliseconds. Like the example below:

**This is my UI Form**

```
type
  TfrmCadPlacas = class(TForm)
    lblNumeroDaPlaca: TLabel;
    ...
    ...
    ...

procedure TfrmCadPlacas.btnSalvarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // ------------- SQL -------------
  if not EstaEditando then
    begin
    InserirPlaca(Placa, Marca, Modelo, Cor, IDLote, IDHistorico,
      dmDados.IDUsuario, dmDados.IDLoteamento);

    ShowMessage(SMsgPlacaInseridaSucesso);
  end;
end;
```

**InserirPlaca procedure**

```
procedure InserirPlaca(Placa, Marca, Modelo, Cor:string; IDLote, IDHistorico, IDUsuario, IDLoteamento: Integer);
var
  qryInserir: TFDQuery;
begin
  qryInserir := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  with qryInserir do
  begin
    Connection := dmDados.FDConnection;
    Active := False;
    SQL.Clear;

    SQL.Add('INSERT INTO ' + T_PLACAS);
    SQL.Add('(' + C_PLACA + ', ');
    SQL.Add(C_MARCA + ', ');
    SQL.Add(C_MODELO + ', ');
    SQL.Add(C_COR + ', ');
    SQL.Add(C_ID_LOTE + ', ');
    SQL.Add(C_ID_HISTORICO + ') ');
    SQL.Add('VALUES (:' + C_PLACA + ', ');
    SQL.Add(':' + C_MARCA + ', ');
    SQL.Add(':' + C_MODELO + ', ');
    SQL.Add(':' + C_COR + ', ');
    SQL.Add(':' + C_ID_LOTE + ', ');
    SQL.Add(':' + C_ID_HISTORICO + ') ');

    Params[0].AsString := Placa;
    Params[1].AsString := Marca;
    Params[2].AsString := Modelo;
    Params[3].AsString := Cor;
    Params[4].AsInteger := IDLote;
    Params[5].AsInteger := PesquisarHistorico(IDLote);

    ExecSQL;
  end;
end;
```

As you can see, I am performing a MySQL Server request in the `MainThread`.

After watching some classes I noticed it is wrong to perform heavy operation in the `UIThread` as it should be only for GUI. In my case, the operation is pretty fast so it doesn't disturb the UI, if the internet connection is good.

Should I put this MySQL Server request in a background Thread?

Comment: I sense a new databreach in the making... ;)  All kidding aside, it is up to you to decide if the delays when interacting with the db are acceptable or not, please note that threading will complicate things.

Comment: That's what I thought, it would be too much work throughout the application to save a quarter of a second.

Comment: "*... if the internet connection is good*" - and if it is not, you will likely freeze up your UI while the system tries to figure out what to do about it.  At the very least, I would suggest displaying a status UI to the user before actually performing the query, and then hide the status when finished.  Otherwise, I would move the query to a worker thread.  And no, threading will not really complicate things that must at all, especially if you use an anonymous thread. The UI thread can wait on the wait on the thread to finish while still servicing the UI.

Comment: I agree, in the end I will be using localhost for BD, so it is very fast and let it in the UI Thread.